# c++ lock_free_queue example tested more slowly than mutex

Tags: c++, queue, mutex, lock-free

i tested the example in book <C++ Concurrency in Action> charpter 7 lock_free_queue and mutex_queue by 2 threads push and 2 threads pop ,the result is using mutex is faster than lock_free queue.here is the lock_free queue code.

so anyone can explain this result? on x86 cpu, the head and tail respectively of lock_free_queue is mutex free,so my first thought is this lock_free_queue will faster than mutex_queue .

here is the mutex queue code:

```
template<typename T>
class LockFreeQueue
{
public:

    struct Node;
    struct CountedNodePtr{
        int external_count;
        Node* ptr;
        CountedNodePtr()noexcept:external_count(0),ptr(nullptr){}
    };

    std::atomic<CountedNodePtr> head;
    std::atomic<CountedNodePtr> tail;

    struct NodeCounter{
        uint32_t internal_count:30;
        uint32_t external_counters:2;
    };
    struct Node{
        std::atomic<T*> data;
        std::atomic<NodeCounter> count;
        CountedNodePtr next;

        Node()noexcept{
            NodeCounter new_count;
            new_count.external_counters = 2;
            new_count.internal_count = 0;
            count.store(new_count);
            data.store(nullptr);
        }
        void ReleaseRef(){
            NodeCounter old_counter = count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            NodeCounter new_counter;
            do{
                new_counter = old_counter;
                --new_counter.internal_count;
            }while(!count.compare_exchange_strong(old_counter, new_counter,
                    std::memory_order_acquire,std::memory_order_relaxed));
            if(!new_counter.internal_count && !new_counter.external_counters){
                delete this;
            }
        }
    };
    static void IncreaseExternalCount(std::atomic<CountedNodePtr>& counter,
                    CountedNodePtr& old_counter){
        CountedNodePtr new_counter;
        do{
            new_counter = old_counter;
            ++new_counter.external_count;
        }while(!counter.compare_exchange_strong(old_counter, new_counter,
                std::memory_order_acquire,std::memory_order_relaxed));
        old_counter.external_count = new_counter.external_count;
    }
    static void FreeExternalCounter(CountedNodePtr& old_node_ptr){
        Node* const ptr = old_node_ptr.ptr;
        int const count_increase = old_node_ptr.external_count-2;

        NodeCounter old_counter = ptr->count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        NodeCounter new_counter;
        do{
            new_counter = old_counter;
            --new_counter.external_counters;
            new_counter.internal_count+=count_increase;
        }while(!ptr->count.compare_exchange_strong(old_counter, new_counter,
                std::memory_order_acquire,std::memory_order_relaxed));
        if(!new_counter.internal_count && !new_counter.external_counters){
            delete ptr;
        }
    }

public:

    LockFreeQueue(){
    CountedNodePtr ptr ;
    ptr.external_count =1;
    ptr.ptr = new Node;
    head.store(ptr);
    tail.store(head.load());
    };

    ~LockFreeQueue(){
        while(Node* const old_head = head.load().ptr){
            head.store(old_head->next);
            delete old_head;
        }
    }
    void Push(T new_value){
        std::unique_ptr<T> new_data = std::make_unique<T>(new_value);
        CountedNodePtr new_next;
        new_next.ptr = new Node;
        new_next.external_count = 1;
        CountedNodePtr old_tail = tail.load();

        for(;;){
            IncreaseExternalCount(tail,old_tail);
            T* old_data = nullptr;
            if(old_tail.ptr->data.compare_exchange_strong(old_data,
                    new_data.get())){
                old_tail.ptr->next = new_next;
                old_tail = tail.exchange(new_next);
                FreeExternalCounter(old_tail);
                new_data.release();
                break;
            }
            old_tail.ptr->ReleaseRef();
        }
    }
    std::unique_ptr<T> Pop(){
        CountedNodePtr old_head = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        for(;;){
            IncreaseExternalCount(head,old_head);
            Node* const ptr = old_head.ptr;
            if(ptr==tail.load().ptr){
                ptr->ReleaseRef();
                return std::unique_ptr<T>();
            }
            if(head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, ptr->next)){
                T* const res = ptr->data.exchange(nullptr);
                FreeExternalCounter(old_head);
                return std::unique_ptr<T>(res);
            }
            ptr->ReleaseRef();
        }
    }
};
// here is the mutex_queue
template <typename T>
class ThreadSafeQueue {
public:
  ThreadSafeQueue() {}
  ThreadSafeQueue& operator=(const ThreadSafeQueue& other) = delete;
  ThreadSafeQueue(const ThreadSafeQueue& other) = delete;

  ~ThreadSafeQueue() { BreakAllWait(); }

  void Enqueue(const T& element) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    queue_.emplace(element);
//    cv_.notify_one();
  }

  bool Dequeue(T* element) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (queue_.empty()) {
      return false;
    }
    *element = std::move(queue_.front());
    queue_.pop();
    return true;
  }

//  bool WaitDequeue(T* element) {
//    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
//    cv_.wait(lock, [this]() { return break_all_wait_ || !queue_.empty(); });
//    if (break_all_wait_) {
//      return false;
//    }
//    *element = std::move(queue_.front());
//    queue_.pop();
//    return true;
//  }

  typename std::queue<T>::size_type Size() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    return queue_.size();
  }

  bool Empty() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    return queue_.empty();
  }

  void BreakAllWait() {
    break_all_wait_ = true;
//    cv_.notify_all();
  }

 private:
  volatile bool break_all_wait_ = false;
  std::mutex mutex_;
  std::queue<T> queue_;

    struct Node{
      int data;
      Node * next;
      Node(const int& d):data(d),next(NULL){}
    };
//  std::condition_variable cv_;
};

// test code added here
#include <iostream>
#include "lock_free_queue.h"
#include "thread_safe_queue.h"
#include "unbounded_queue.h"
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
//#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#ifndef MDC_TEST

using namespace rudder::base;
using namespace apollo::cyber::base;
using namespace std;
struct Student
{
    int a;
    double b;
    float c;
};
typedef int swr_ele_t; // 元素
int cycles;
typedef struct swr_queue
{   // 队列结构
    std::atomic<size_t> head;
    std::atomic<size_t> tail;
    swr_ele_t *eles;
    size_t size;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;

} swr_queue_t;

LockFreeQueue<swr_ele_t> lock_queue_test[7];
ThreadSafeQueue<swr_ele_t> mutex_queue_test[7];
UnboundedQueue<swr_ele_t> unbounde_queue_test[7];

bool LockPush(const swr_ele_t *ele,int i)
{
        lock_queue_test[i].Push(*ele);
        return true;
};
bool LockPop(swr_ele_t *ele,int i)
{
    auto tmp = lock_queue_test[i].Pop();
    if(tmp == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        *ele = *tmp;
//      std::cout<<"tmp"<<*tmp<<std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};
bool MutexPush(const swr_ele_t *ele,int i)
{
    mutex_queue_test[i].Enqueue(*ele);
    return true;
};
bool MutexPop(swr_ele_t *ele,int i)
{
    swr_ele_t tmp;
    if(mutex_queue_test[i].Dequeue(&tmp))
    {
        *ele = tmp;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
bool UnboundedPush(const swr_ele_t *ele,int i)
{
    unbounde_queue_test[i].Enqueue(*ele);
    return true;
};
bool UnboundedPop(swr_ele_t *ele,int i)
{
    swr_ele_t tmp;
    if(unbounde_queue_test[i].Dequeue(&tmp))
    {
        *ele = tmp;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
/***************************测试程序部分******************************/
typedef bool (*push_fn_t)(const swr_ele_t *,int);
typedef bool (*pop_fn_t)(swr_ele_t *,int);

// 线程参数
typedef struct thead_arg
{
    //swr_queue_t *queue;
    char type;
    push_fn_t push;
    pop_fn_t pop;
    double push_time;
    double pop_time;
    int i;
} thead_arg_t;

// 计时器: 毫秒
double time_diff(struct timespec *start, struct timespec *end)
{
    long sec = end->tv_sec - start->tv_sec;
    long nsec = end->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec;
    return sec * 1000.0 + nsec / 1000000.0;
}

void *thread_func(void *a)
{
    thead_arg_t *arg = (thead_arg_t *)a;
    //swr_queue_t *queue = arg->queue;

    struct timespec time1, time2;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);

    if (arg->type == 'W')
    { // Producer
        swr_ele_t e = cycles;
        while (true)
        {
            if (arg->push(&e,arg->i))
            {
                if ((--e) < 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    { // Consumer

        while (true)
        {
            swr_ele_t e;
//          cout<<"arg->pop"<<std::endl;
            if (arg->pop(&e,arg->i))
            {
//              cout<<"pop"<<e <<std::endl;
                // if (e % 1000000 == 0) printf("pop ele: %d\n", e);
                if (e == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
    if(arg->type == 'W')
    {
        arg->push_time = time_diff(&time1, &time2);
    }
    else
    {
        arg->pop_time =  time_diff(&time1, &time2);
    }
    printf("%c %d Time=%fms\n", arg->type, arg->i,time_diff(&time1, &time2));
//    printf("%f ", arg->type, time_diff(&time1, &time2));
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
//  std::cout<<"argv"<< argv[1]<<std::endl;;
    std::cout<<"core_num is : "<<std::thread::hardware_concurrency()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"lock free head" <<lock_queue_test[0].head.is_lock_free()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"lock free tail" <<lock_queue_test[0].tail.is_lock_free()<<std::endl;
    int num = 0;

    while(num<7)
    {
        cycles = 10000;
        struct test_case
        {
            push_fn_t push;
            pop_fn_t pop;
            const char *desc;
        } cases[] = {
            //{LockPush, LockPop, "LockPush, LockPop"},
            {MutexPush, MutexPop, "MutexPush,MutexPop"},
//            {UnboundedPush, UnboundedPop, "UnboundedPush,UnboundedPop"},
        };
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < sizeof(cases) / sizeof(cases[0]); ++k)
        {
            printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("%s\n", cases[k].desc);
            swr_queue_t queue;

            const int NUM = 6;
            pthread_t tids[NUM];
            thead_arg_t args[NUM];

            int i;//0 1 2 3
//            for (i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
//            {
//              args[i].i = num;
//               // args[i].queue = &queue;
//                args[i].type = (i+1)%2 == 1 ? 'W' : 'R';
//                args[i].push = cases[k].push;
//                args[i].pop = cases[k].pop;
////                printf("pthread_create start");
//                pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, thread_func, args + i);
//            }

            for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                args[i].i = num;
               // args[i].queue = &queue;
                args[i].type =  'W';

                args[i].push = cases[k].push;
                args[i].pop = cases[k].pop;
//                printf("pthread_create start");
                pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, thread_func, args + i);
//                pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
//                printf("pthread_create %d",args[i].i);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
            }
            for (i = 3; i < 6; ++i)
            {
                args[i].i = num;
               // args[i].queue = &queue;
                args[i].type =  'R';

                args[i].push = cases[k].push;
                args[i].pop = cases[k].pop;
//                printf("pthread_create start");
                pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, thread_func, args + i);
//                pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
//                printf("pthread_create %d",args[i].i);
            }
            for (i = 3; i < 6; ++i)
            {
                pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
            }
            printf("\n");
//            printf("total time=%fms\n", args[0].push_time + args[1].pop_time);
//            printf("%f\n", args[0].push_time + args[1].pop_time);

        }
        num++;
    }

    return 0;
}





#endif /* MDC_TEST */
```

Comment: You probably need to show your time measurements and test application. Also are you running a release build? I have seen cases were the debug application took 100 times as long as release for the same code and data.

Comment: So many people thinks that blindly using lock free would make your app faster. No it does not work that way.

Comment: now i added the test code .all the test are running in debug build.

Comment: Run it in release mode.

Comment: lock-free is often good in low-contention situations, but if you benchmark *just* the queue, you probably have both reader and writer hammering on it full-time.